# How to display query result in a particular format

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two columns named FirstName and LastName. I want to query these from the table and display them in the format "FirstName  LastName" (Note there is a space between FirstName and LastName) under the same column.

**Edit 1**

I tried this

[image]

and the result comes like this

[image]

Why am I getting 0's ?

Comment: If you want to do this in the query then what RDBMS? If you want to do it in the presentation layer then what are you using for that?

Comment: oracle: select firstname || ' ' || lastname from table where col=val . I didn't want to answer because not enough info yet.

Comment: @MJB - That hasn't stopped 3 other people from leaping in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string concatenation operator in SQLite [appears to be](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) `||`. So (assuming that the columns are both `NOT NULL`-able)

```
SELECT FirstName || ' ' || LastName FROM Users
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName FROM Users
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName
from SomeTable
```